# Shapefile buffer assigning to each buffer a different length

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, buffer

I have drawn a set of lines (corresponding to a network) in a shapefile. I would like to buffer them, but each line has a different buffer length, so I thought to do it with Python: for each branch, identified by a particular ID number, perform the buffer up to a certain distance that you can find in an attribute column.

To do so, I would like to use: 
Buffer_analysis {all_my_branches, a_new_defined_layer, an_attribute_column_inserted_in_the_shapefile}

I imported arcpy, I set as arcpy.env.workspace my shapefile, but when I ask for the list of feature classes I get the answer:

```
"function ListFeatureClasses at 0x1948B770"
```

So I guess I have no features in my shapefile. How can I therefore do to perform the buffer I want? Can it be done on a shapefile?

I am new to ArcGIS and Python.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you right, but if you want to create a buffer with a distance that is written as an attribute to the objects the buffer will surround: there is an option for this in the buffer tool: "buffer distance field". Maybe you need to post some visual data to make the task clear.

Comment: I agree with @Papierwolf that this sounds like it only needs the Buffer tool and no ArcPy code.

Comment: Please post the script that you have been using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the two commentators mentioned, you don't need `arcpy` for this task. In the interface of the `Buffer (Analysis)` tool, just select your shapefile and then specify the buffer distance field here:

[image: buffer distance]

---

You **can** however, use `arcpy` for this task too. Try this:

```
import arcpy

# Define workspace
workspace = r"C:Path\to\workspace"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace

# Define Inputs
your_input = r"C:Path\to\shapefile\shapefile.shp"
your_output = r"C:Path\to\output\output.shp"
distance_field = "Name_of_Distance_Field_in_Input"

# Perform Buffer
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(your feature, your_output, distance_field, "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL")
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers. Yeah actually I could have also used the default buffer function, but I was trying to learn how to use python (also because I think I will have to do more complex stuff soon). 
So I did as you suggested me, and this what I got:


my_input = r"C:\Users\tsacco\ArcGIS\GB.shp"
my_output = r"C:\Users\tsacco\ArcGIS\Output.shp"
distance_field = my_input["Buff_Size"]
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Why did this occur? Buff_Size is a column of numbers

Comment: @TommasoSacco Sorry, my bad, it's not necessary to reference the "Name_of_Distance_Field". Try my code again, it should work now. And for making the code complete, I also added a workspace.

Comment: I tried also to do the other way, without declaring it, as you said, but now I get the error: "Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Buff_Size' is not defined". I checked the Directory, and the one I setted corresponds to where the shapefile GB, that I load as "my_input" is, so what could be the problem? In the GB file there is an attribute called "Buff_Size" that is my input for the buffer analyisis. 
May it be because I have not defined the output yet (i.e. there is not Output.shp in my folder yet)?

Comment: Is your "Buff_Size" in a seperate feature class? Then this would be the source of the error. I tested the code with a GDB and a feature class as input and it worked without any problem. The "Buff_Size" attribute need to be in "your_input" feature class. You don't need to create an output file beforehand, it will do so in the process.

Comment: In case you still run into problems I suggest you post the code to your original question, so we can have a look at it.

Comment: I am not sure what was the problem, but now it works. Most probably I had some defining the input parameters. Maybe it was because I did not paid attention to the use of slashes and backslashes.